# Onclick change tab visibilities?

Tags: javascript

I am designing an ecommerce system and on the product page there will be several tabs for information. I need a solution that when clicked on the tab it will change the style element of the HTML's CSS to `style="visibility: visibile'"` for the selected tab and other tabs to `style="visibility: hidden;"`.

Is there a simple way of doing this with `OnClick=""` in the HTML? Javascript isn't really my strong suite I apologize.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleVisibility(id) {
        var tabs_class = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");

        var tabs_id = document.getElementById(id);

        for ( var i = 0; i > tabs_class.length; i++){
            tabs_class[i].style.display = "none";
        }

        tabs_id.style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>

<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="active">
        <a onclick="toggleVisibility('product_description');">Description</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('product_photos');">Photos</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a onclick="toggleVisibility('product_reviews');">Reviews</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a onclick="toggleVisibility('return_policy');">Return Policy</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab" id="product_description">
    <p>{$product_description}</p>
</div>
<div class="tab" id="product_photos" style="display: none;">
    <p>Product Photos</p>
</div>
<div class="tab" id="product_reviews" style="display: none;">
    <p>Reviews</p>
</div>
<div class="tab" id="return_policy" style="display: none;">
    <p>Return Policy</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please use unobtrusive listeners rather than embedding JS in `onclick` attributes.

Answer (score 2):

### Native JavaScript:

```
// get all tags
var tags = document.getElementsByClassName("tag");

// register onclick event on tags
tags.addEventListener('click', modifyVisibility, false);

function modifyVisibility() {
    // set all to hidden
    tags.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    // set clicked tag to visible
    this.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Comment: Similar to what I am looking for. But I need it a button above the `<div>` which will be hidden to target the specific div and change visibility from hidden to visibile.

Answer (score 0):

If you include JQuery you can use the following to change the "display" property:

```
<div id='clickMe' onclick='$("#clickMe").hide()'>Click on me!</div>
```

Or without JQuery you can do this:

```
<div id='clickMe' onclick='this.style.display = "none";'>Click on me!</div>
```

If you need the "visibility" property changed, you can do this:

```
<div id='clickMe' onclick='this.style.visibility = "hidden";'>Click on me!</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to include the whole jquery library for one simple thing.

Comment: I know that it changes CSS display.  I didn't know if he cared about the difference.  You can also use this.style.visibility = "hidden" if you care.

Comment: you missed the sign in for  for ( var i = 0; i < tabs_class.length; i++){

Answer (score 0):

Instead of handling the tabs on your own, why not use jQueryUI to do the tabs for you.  Check the example below:

https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
<div id="popupInfo">
  <div class="closeButton" 
      onclick="document.getElementById('popupInfo').style.visibility = 'hidden';">
 </div>
contents....
</div>
```

where closebutton uses a .png containing an 'X' in two shades of grey...

```
.closeButton
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background: transparent url(4x4_X.png);
    right: 5px;
    top: 5px;
}
.closeButton:hover
{
    background-position: 0px -32px;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply include in their guides a class and get the same and add style

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("className");
for(var i = 0; i > elements.lenght; i++){
     elements[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
}
current.style.visibility = "visibile";
```

Comment: Tried working something siliar to your example, I updated original post with code. Not working though.

Comment: Correction, it is changing them to `display: block;` based on the ID, but it isn't changing the `display: none;` based on CLASS.

Comment: Caught mistake. You had `i > #elements.length` needed a < symbol instead.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will allow buttons to set the CSS display property to `display: none;` for all elements with specified class. It will also set the element with the specified ID to `display: block;`.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function toggleVisibility(id) {
            var tabs_class = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");

            var tabs_id = document.getElementById(id);

            for ( var i = 0; i < tabs_class.length; i++ ) {
                tabs_class[i].style.display = "none";
            }

            tabs_id.style.display = "block";
        }
    </script>

    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="active">
            <a onclick="toggleVisibility('product_description');">Description</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('product_photos');">Photos</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a onclick="toggleVisibility('product_reviews');">Reviews</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a onclick="toggleVisibility('return_policy');">Return Policy</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab" id="product_description">
        <p>{$product_description}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab" id="product_photos" style="display: none;">
        <p>Product Photos</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab" id="product_reviews" style="display: none;">
        <p>Reviews</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab" id="return_policy" style="display: none;">
        <p>Return Policy</p>
    </div>
```